Cannot unpack flatbuffers in python - struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least
I am new to flatbuffers and I got a device which is sending me flatbuffers encoded as base64 inside a JSON via MQTT.
I am not in control of this device and cannot influence it. I need to deal with the input on the application side.
I got the schema file and generated the respective python classes out of it
namespace FlatbuffersDemo;

table GeneralStruct {
  class_id:uint;
  score:float;
}

table StructData {
  struct_list:[GeneralStruct];
}

table StructTop {
  perception:StructData;
}

root_type StructTop;

Here is now what I am doing in my python code (I extracted the string out of a JSON message).
inference = "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"
buf_decode = base64.b64decode(inference)


ppl_out = StructTop.StructTop.GetRootAs(buf_decode, 0)
cls_data = ppl_out.Perception()

I am getting then the following error on the last row
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/decode_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    cls_data = ppl_out.Perception()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxx/FlatbuffersDemo/ClassificationTop.py", line 29, in Perception
    o = flatbuffers.number_types.UOffsetTFlags.py_type(self._tab.Offset(4))
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flatbuffers/table.py", line 37, in Offset
    vtable = self.Pos - self.Get(N.SOffsetTFlags, self.Pos)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flatbuffers/table.py", line 93, in Get
    return flags.py_type(encode.Get(flags.packer_type, self.Bytes, off))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flatbuffers/encode.py", line 26, in Get
    return packer_type.unpack_from(memoryview_type(buf), head)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 3208642564 bytes for unpacking 4 bytes at offset 3208642560 (actual buffer size is 4004)

I am not really sure where to start investigating. Is that an issue with my python code or is something wrong that the schema is not matching with the actual data?

Looks like the data is corrupt, since it is finding an offset of size 3208642560 at the beginning of the buffer. You should probably hex dump the contents of buf_decode and then see if its contents describes what looks like FlatBuffer (see e.g. https://flatbuffers.dev/flatbuffers_internals.html)
